# MongoDB not updating with Put request, Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, mongodb, put, next.js13

I am using Postman to test my endpoints and everything is working except for updating my documents in Mongodb, I am using PUT request and this is my code, the file path: src/app/api/users/[id]

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectMongoDB from "../../../../../libs/mongodb";
import User from "../../../../../models/user";

export async function PUT(request, { params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const {
    newFirstName: first_name,
    newLastName: last_name,
    newTitle: title,
    newDepartment: department,
    newGroup: group,
  } = await request.json();
  await connectMongoDB();
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    title,
    department,
    group,
  });
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "User Updated" }, { status: 200 });
}
```

I am getting a status 405 Method Not Allowed when I send the request in postman, I am also using the right id as a param.

first time asking, so my apologies if I didn't explain myself

I tried adding all fields in the request or just couple and I am getting the same mistake, I also check the permits and access with MongoDB and everything seems right, I want to be able to update a document in my database

Comment: What request URL are you using?

Comment: Since you're using [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers), the filename should be something like `app/api/users/[id]/route.js`

Comment: you are right @Phil, that is the route, the URL is http://localhost:3000/api/users?id=650a2a93fab6ed9e40c1a99c

Comment: Right, your URL is incorrect. Params are part of the path, not the query string. You want `http://localhost:3000/api/users/650a2a93fab6ed9e40c1a99c`. See [Dynamic Route Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments)